# $\sin(z)=0$ periodic of $2k\pi$ or $k\pi$?

Tags: complex-numbers

is the result of $\sin(z)$$=$ $0$

> $k\pi $ , or $2k\pi$

?

and it's the same for $\cos(z)$ $=0$

> $k \frac{\pi}{2}$

?

Comment: The sine function has a (minimum) period $2\pi$ so it vanishes at every even multiple of $\pi$, because $\sin0=0$. On the other hand, $\sin\pi=0$, so by periodicity, the sine also vanishes at the odd multiples of $\pi$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is $$\sin(x)=0$$ if $$x=k\pi$$ where $k$ is an integer number. And $$2k\pi$$ is the period of the function.

Comment: but for instance cos(z)=1  for 2kpi right ?

Comment: Yes $$\cos(x)=1$$ if $$x=2k\pi$$

Comment: @xmaionx Remember that $\sin(\cdot)$ and $\cos(\cdot)$ hit 0 twice as often as 1. They go through 0 both when going from the negatives to the positives, and when going from the positives to the negatives. On the other hand, they hit 1 only once per $2\pi$ period.

Answer (score 0):

$\sin z = 0 \iff z = n \pi \, (n \in \mathbb{Z})$

Answer (score 0):

Even in complex numbers, those are only solutions for $\sin(z)=0$. 
$$\sin(z) := \frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i} = 0 \iff e^{iz}=e^{-iz} \iff \exists_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} \,iz+2ik\pi=-iz \iff \exists_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} \,z=k\pi$$
Try the same for cosine.